# what is the difference between .net infrastructure vs framework

Tags: c#, .net

I want to ask you difference of .net infrastructure and framework. When i try to create class library project, visual studio offer me infrastructure like **.NET Framework 4.7.2**, **.NET Framework 4.8** etc versions. But when i try to create console application it offers me framework like **.NET 6**, **.NET 7** etc. versions.

Comment: Pay attention to the name of the project template you select when you create the project.  If it has ".NET" in the name then you'll target a modern version of .NET and get to select 5.0 through 7.0.  If it has ".NET Framework" in the name then you'll target the legacy version of .NET and get to select 2.0 through 4.8

Answer (score 1):

That's not true. If you select a project template that targets .NET Framework then you will be prompted to select a version of the .NET Framework. Those project templates have ".NET Framework" in the name. Those project templates that do not specify that they target .NET Framework will target .NET Core, so you will be prompted to select a version of .NET Core. .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core. You can create class library projects targeting either .NET Framework or .NET core and you can do the same for Console application projects.

Because .NET Framework is not being developed beyond version 4.8.x, they have dropped the "Core" from the name, because it's the only game in town. .NET 5 was supposed to be a merger of .NET Core and .NET Framework, which basically means an evolution of .NET Core that adds more features like those of .NET Framework.